# Is there an alternative to {} that also expands to nothing?

Tags: tex-core

I have a weird bug in my text editor that causes it to incorrectly indent any lines that start with special characters, such as greek letters.

```
 % My editor will indent the leading spaces in this line incorrectly.
     Γ ⊢ ...
```

One workaround I found was to add a `{}` at the start of the line. My editor indents things correctly if the first character in the line is an ASCII character and adding a `{}` doesn't change any formatting

```
 % My workaround
     {} Γ ⊢ ...
```

Is there a less noisy alternative to the `{}`? I tried `~` and `\` but both of add an extra space that modifies the formatting of the generated document.

Comment: It seems like a problem with the visual display of indentation would better be solved through the editor (or by changing editors) than by adding TeX commands that have no typesetting function.

Comment: Your use of `{}` here might in fact add extra space...

Comment: @Werner: Why? I couldn't notice any changes in the resulting pdf once I added the {}

Comment: You can use `\relax` instead of `{}`.

Comment: @hugomg: Compile [this paste](http://pastebin.com/RxmmJ7ri).

Comment: it's not clear to me whether the indentation is in the editor view or in the output (if nothing is put at the beginning of the "indented" line).  if only in the editor view, the tag should be changed.

Comment: The question is not very clear but certainly `{}` does not expand to nothing and typically will affect spacing. Compare `one two` and `one {} two`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not very clear but certainly `{}` does not expand to nothing and typically will affect spacing.

Compare

```
one two and one {} two
```

Plain TeX and LaTeX do have a command `\empty` defined (effectively) as

```
\def\empty{}
```

which does expand to nothing so you could use `\empty`, but it would seem better to fix the configuration in the editor rather than add weird stuff to the TeX file.